# apt-get install is not working because of dpkg, how to solve

Tags: apt, dpkg

I can't install any thing using

```
apt-get install
```

It gives this error:

> E: could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource
>   temporarily unavailable)
>   E: unable to lock the administration directory (var/lib/dpkg), its
>   another process using it

I tried

```
dpkg --configure -a 
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process.

dpkg --configure -a --force-congnew dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process.
```

Although I have shut down and restart the system to kill all other hidden process but do not know how to fix it.

I am using all these commands as a super user.

Answer (score 2):

### Remove broken locks

1. Be sure any process is still running associated with these locks:

   `sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

   `sudo lsof /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`

   `sudo lsof /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`

If all of these commands output is empty, you can proceed.

2. Remove any locks you find in these locations:

   `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`

   `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`
3. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
4. Try with `sudo apt-get install` again.

You should have superuser privileges to run those commands.

Comment: .......not working. same error mate

Comment: Which software are you trying to install?

Comment: Have you aborted some `apt-get` or `dpkg` command?

Comment: i am trying to install pymol and raccoon, both of them can be easily installed on nay ubunto or fedora.

Comment: actually i heard this dpkg term for the first time so i guess i never aborted any of them. This is a work station and normally remains ON all the time.

Comment: Edited my answer to provide you more alternatives.