# sudo apt-get update returns an error

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate somewhere. I apologize for the repeat. I'm running Xubuntu 14.04.
For some odd reason my pc is running slow today, so I thought it might have something to do with the software, so I did an update, and
**sudo apt-get update** returns an error:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I tried the answer given in 
[apt-get install is not working because of dpkg, how to solve](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797609/apt-get-install-is-not-working-because-of-dpkg-how-to-solve)
and this is the following result:

```
$ sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
aptitude 2166 root    3uW  REG  252,0        0 49021509 /var/lib/dpkg/lock

$ sudo lsof /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.

$ sudo lsof /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.

$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process
```

1. **How do I fix this?**
2. Could someone walk me thru the steps?
3. Why would I need a "lock" on an open directory?
4. How do I find what process is using it?
5. How do I check my hardware if that's the culprit??

I will try a reboot, and see if that fixes anything. Be right back.

---

OK, NOW after rebooting I get the following results:|

```
$ sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.

$ sudo lsof /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.

$ sudo lsof /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: status error on /var/cache/apt/archives/lock: No such file or directory
lsof 4.86
 latest revision: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/
 latest FAQ: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ
 latest man page: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof_man
 usage: [-?abhKlnNoOPRtUvVX] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+D D] [+|-f[gG]] [+|-e s]
 [-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [+|-L [l]] [+m [m]] [+|-M] [-o [o]] [-p s]
[+|-r [t]] [-s [p:s]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [--] [names]
Use the ``-h'' option to get more help information.
```

I also tried

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

which may have worked cause when I did

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I got NO ERRORS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna answer your questions a bit out of order, because I can.

> **How do I check my hardware if that's the culprit??**

Is your computer working? If so, your hardware isn't causing the problem.

> **Why would I need a "lock" on an open directory?**

DPKG/Apt locks `/var/lib/dpkg` to ensure that it can install software in peace, without causing any conflicts to the database of installed packages (present at `/var/lib/dpkg/status`). It's a safety mechanism to keep APT from blowing itself up by accident.

> **How do I find what process is using it?**

You already have! Look at the output of: `sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock`:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
aptitude 2166 root    3uW  REG  252,0        0 49021509 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

The program `aptitude` (a pretty package manager) is active, and is the current owner of the lock.

> **How do I fix this? Could someone walk me thru the steps?**

There are a few things you can do.

First off, you can just break the lock by running `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`. However, it's a good idea not to break this lock to force other `apt` processes to run, as you may be interrupting something important, which may leave your system in an unusable state. Only do this if you're 100% sure that `apt` or `dpkg` isn't running. You can check this by running `ps -aux | grep dpkg` or `ps -aux | grep apt`. If either of these return anything other than a line with `grep` in it, it's unsafe to break the lock.

Secondly, you can go around to all of your terminals to see where `aptitude` is being run, and to check up on it. If you cannot find the terminal that it's on, the `w` command will help you a lot.

Third, you can just kill the process by force, although this may still need you to break the lock. Do this by running `sudo kill <PID>`, where `<PID>` is the number in the `lsof` entry, in your case, `2166`. Do not run `kill -9` for apt, as it will forcefully kill it, while regular `kill` will give apt a chance to clean everything up before it dies. You can also kill the process by rebooting, logging off, or exiting the terminal it's running in.

If you do forcefully kill `apt` and break the lock, it's a very good idea to run `dpkg --configure -a` to let DPKG fix what was potentially broken.

Comment: so - 'sudo kill 2166' - will stop the process by force? Bad news (maybe), I already used - sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock - am I screwed or is there hope?

Comment: @hienz1 If you rebooted your computer and have already done `dpkg --configure -a`, **your system will be fine**. To answer your second question, the `kill` command will (by default) send something called Signal 15, which asks a process nicely to gracefully exit, which is usually safe. By adding `-9`, the `kill` command will forcefully close the command, which can be unsafe. See `man kill` for more details.

Comment: THANK YOU so much, Kaz Wolfe, that's a great weight off my shoulders. :-)

Comment: @hienz1 No worries! It's what AskUbuntu is here for!

Answer (score 0):

1. Restart your system to ensure apt is not running
2. Delete the lock file (`sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`)

The lock file prevents multiple instances of apt to run at once

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Which file should I delete, what's it called? And is the terminal command to do that "sudo apt-get del"?

Comment: The command is rm and the file is /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Comment: results:
$ rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file ‘/var/lib/dpkg/lock’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/dpkg/lock’: Permission denied

Comment: You need to use sudo

Comment: sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock - returned no activity, so I'm assuming it worked

Answer (score 0):

> 4. How do I find what process is using it?

```
ps -fea | grep apt
```

Then, once you have identified the process, you may need to kill it.

```
kill -9 nnnn
```

Where `nnnn` is the process number.

[Restarting the computer will also kill it but often just logging out and back in works, depending who owns the process causing the issue.]

Comment: The results of ................... '$ ps -fea | grep apt ........................ hienz1 , 4126 , 2855 , 0 00:31 , pts/0 , 00:00:00 , grep --color=auto apt'

Comment: which is the process number?